# How to blur with css3 inside the parent's container box?

Tags: html, css

The css3 blur effect ignores the parent container dimensions and gets overflow. I need to have something that acts an inner-blur with **css3**. Its that possible? Any trick?

html

```
<div class="box">
      <div class="blur">
           <img src="..." />
      </div>
</div>​
```

css

```
.box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.blur{
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Blur overflow **example**:

http://jsfiddle.net/ngJEr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.box{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
}

.blur{
-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/ngJEr/8/